# Image on orientationchange

Tags: css

i tried to make app.

and i have two galleries , one for orientation portrait and the other for landscape.

how can i remove the image when i change from landscape to portrait?

my problem is when i change to the portrait orientation, the image from landscape is hidden  but still in the top. because the image showing in the portrait orientation have a space from the top.

i use the code inspector to look what are the problem, and show me a hidden image from the landscape orientation.

thx for any help

Comment: Can’t you just use different CSS styles based on the orientation media query? http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation